# How to concatenate variables that are not undefined in Node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a large number of variables - as below, and some of them may not be defined. What would be a clean way to skip all undefined ones?

```
var sig = pin + order.id + order.operation_number + 
order.operation_type + order.operation_status + order.operation_amount 
+ order.operation_currency + order.operation_withdrawal_amount + 
order.operation_commission_amount + order.is_completed + 
order.operation_original_amount + order.operation_original_currency + 
order.operation_datetime + order.operation_related_number + 
order.control + order.description + order.email + order.p_info + 
order.p_email + order.credit_card_issuer_identification_number + 
order.credit_card_masked_number + order.credit_card_expiration_year + 
order.credit_card_expiration_month + order.credit_card_brand_codename 
+ order.credit_card_brand_code + order.credit_card_id + order.channel 
+ order.channel_country + order.geoip_country;
```

Answer (score 2):

If you can get all these values you want to concatenate into an array, you can just use `join()` to put the rest together. Something like:

```js
let order = {
    credit_card_brand_codename: "Code Name",
    credit_card_brand_code: "Brand Code",
    credit_card_id: "Card Id",
    channel : undefined
}

// the names you want to join
let values = [
    order.credit_card_brand_codename,
    order.credit_card_brand_code,
    order.credit_card_id,
    order.channel,
    order.someUnknownKey
]

let s = values.join('_') // or .join('') to simply concat
console.log(s)
```

This will handle names, who's value is undefined. Keep in mind it is still an error to try to use undeclared names so you can't randomly add a bunch of unknown variable to the list.

Answer (score 1):

Probably the `values.join('')` is the better solution but if you want to go fancy, you can use the tagged template literal to filter out falsy values and return a clean string.

Just to show that there is such a thing, here's an example:

```js
function filter(strings, ...values) {
  
  let res = '';
  strings.forEach((string, i) => {
    
    if (values[i]) {
      
      res += string + values[i];
    }
  });
  
  return res;
}

const test = filter`${undefined}${'something'}${123}${undefined}`;

console.log(test);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const arr = [pin , order.id , order.operation_number , 
  order.operation_type , order.operation_status , order.operation_amount 
  , order.operation_currency , order.operation_withdrawal_amount , 
  order.operation_commission_amount , order.is_completed , 
  order.operation_original_amount , order.operation_original_currency , 
  order.operation_datetime , order.operation_related_number , 
  order.control , order.description , order.email , order.p_info , 
  order.p_email , order.credit_card_issuer_identification_number , 
  order.credit_card_masked_number , order.credit_card_expiration_year , 
  order.credit_card_expiration_month , order.credit_card_brand_codename 
  , order.credit_card_brand_code , order.credit_card_id , order.channel 
  , order.channel_country , order.geoip_country];
arr.filter(a => a != undefined).join();
```

Filter out what you do not need and than joint it.

Answer (score 0):

Here is simple solution, just use `Object.keys` to get the keys and `reduce` to concatenate the results

```
// You order object
const order = {
  id: 1050 ,
  operation_status: undefined,
  operation_type: 'unknown',
  operation_amount: undefined
};

// Get the keys and then reduce to combine the results
const sig = Object.keys(order).reduce((all, item) => {
  if (order[item]) {
    all = `${all} ${order[item]}`;
  }
  return all;
}, '');

// Log
console.log(sig);
```

[Example](https://repl.it/@gilbertfrausto/SurprisedSuddenAnimatronics)

Answer (score -1):

This is a **bad way** after you concat and noticed values **undefined** in your string. You can **replace** them to empty. (LOL)

```
var pin = "I123"
var order = {id: 100}

var sig = pin + order.id + order.operation_number +
order.operation_type + order.operation_status + order.operation_amount
+ order.operation_currency + order.operation_withdrawal_amount +
order.operation_commission_amount + order.is_completed +
order.operation_original_amount + order.operation_original_currency +
order.operation_datetime + order.operation_related_number +
order.control + order.description + order.email + order.p_info +
order.p_email + order.credit_card_issuer_identification_number +
order.credit_card_masked_number + order.credit_card_expiration_year +
order.credit_card_expiration_month + order.credit_card_brand_codename
+ order.credit_card_brand_code + order.credit_card_id + order.channel
+ order.channel_country + order.geoip_country;

console.log(sig);
// I123100undefinedundefinedundefinedundefinedundefinedundefinedundefinedundefinedundefinedundefinedundefinedundefinedundefinedundefinedundefinedundefinedundefinedundefinedundefinedundefinedundefinedundefinedundefinedundefinedundefinedundefinedundefined
```

You can **replace** if you want

```
sig = sig.replace(/undefined/g, '');
console.log(sig); // I123100
```

**Why I mentioned this is a bad way?**

Because if your data contains *undefined* string, it will remove it from your data. This will lose data integrity.

This is **a better way** without **list all attributes of `order`** by loop it's keys. This is very simple.

```
var sig = pin;
for (key in order) sig += order[key] || '';
console.log(sig);
```

And if you want to **determine attributes** should be concat by in `order`, you can use `map` and `join`

```
const keys = [
  'id', 'operation_number', 'operation_type'
  // any attribute you want...
];

var sig = pin + keys.map(i => order[i] || '').join('')
console.log(sig);
```

Hope it'll help you :))

Comment: Doesn't always work: `['i-contain-undefined', undefined].join('').replace(/undefined/g, '')` will evaluate to `'i-contain-'`

Comment: @NinoFiliu, I've mentioned this is **a bad way**, and I also had other ways to resolve the problem. Tnx